# How can i make a multi level query using SOQL in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am running the nested query

```
  SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name,
(SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name
    FROM OrderItems)
  FROM Order
```

This is only 1 level deep.
Is there an example which can show me how to make a 3 to 5 level deep select in SOQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL is limited in that subqueries like you show are only allowed at a single level.

However, you can go higher (5 levels) if you do bottom up.

E.g. we rewrite your query like so:

```
SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name,
Order.Id, Order.Name, Order.Account.Name, 
Order.Account.Parent.Name,
Order.Account.Parent.Parent.Name, 
Order.Account.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name, 
Order.Pricebook2.Name
FROM OrderItem
```

To get some account hierarchy.
It's clunky as SOQL is, but you get the idea

Comment: if i run the above query i get no rows back, but if i run the example i gave i get teh Id, Name, Account.Name and OrderItems ?

Comment: well it's probably because you DO NOT have 4 levels of account hierarchy. It will only return rows with data so trim it down to what you have, e.g. like for like `SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name,
Order.Id, Order.Name, Order.Account.Name,
FROM OrderItem`

Comment: as you mentioned like for like, so i ran the query SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name, Order.Id, Order.Name, Order.Account.Name, FROM OrderItem , which is equivalent to my initial and still no data is returned

Comment: Does the order have any `OrderItem`? In your original query, does it return orderitems?

Comment: No , it returned no orderitems

Comment: Well then of course this query will return nothing as well :) you're no longer querying orders, you're querying items. As I mentioned, this technique is bottom up, not top down. You're stuck with 1 level if you want to go top down.

Comment: so if i and products to my Order the second query you provided should work ?

Comment: @Kelly yes it will work

Comment: also one other thing , just to get a better understanding of this , your query with the levels is  3 levels deep ?

Comment: `Order.Account.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name` -> this is 5 levels deep. The object you're querying is `OrderItem` and you go to it's Order then ORder's account then parent-parent-parent

Comment: ok got it thankyou. Is there no UI query builder in Salesforce or an app they provide that can help build this ? Because you really need to know your data in Salesforce to know how many levels you  can query /

Comment: @Kelly well there is object diagram builder right in SF and you can write queries using workbench. But in general, yes, working with ANY database implies you know your schema :)

Comment: yes workbench is good . Is the object diagram builder in SF called Schemapuker or does SF have one built in ?

Comment: Go to https://<YOURORG>.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiL191aS9wbGF0Zm9ybS9zY2hlbWEvdWkvc2NoZW1hYnVpbGRlci9TY2hlbWFCdWlsZGVyVWkifSwic3RhdGUiOnt9fQ%3D%3D

Comment: Or in the UI - Setup -> Object Manager -> Schema Builder

Comment: Sorry to ask so much , does it let you select the fields to select and construct a query like in sql where it can construct the inner joins for you ?

Comment: @Kelly no, that's not a query building tool, it's a schema visualiser so you can see how objects relate to each other and show their fields.

Comment: for the multi level query is there any sample c# app that can run that query  and present the data with columns in a table ? Maybe running Database.Query(userQuery + ' LIMIT 10'), where userQuery would be the 5 level query you provided above ?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce increased the limit from 1-level to 5-levels deep: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm

```
SELECT Name,
    (SELECT LastName,
        (SELECT AssetLevel,
            (SELECT Description,
                (SELECT LineItemNumber FROM WorkOrderLineItems)    
            FROM WorkOrders)    
        FROM Assets)    
    FROM Contacts)    
FROM Account
```